# Two independent random variable with the same density.

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, density-function

There is a task:

Let $ X1, X2 $ – independent random variables with the same density $\quad {2x \over{a^2} } \quad 0 < x < a $.

Let additionally  $ \quad Y = max(X1, X2),\quad Z = min(X1, X2) $.

A) What is the value of expected value and variance of r.v. $X1$.

B) What is the form of density and expected value $Y$?

C) Find density and expected value af random variable $Z$.

Soo... I found the value of expected value and variance of r.v $X1$ and they are:

$E(X1) = {2a \over 3}$

$V(X1) = {a^2 \over 18} $

Then I found expected value and density of Y as follow:

$ F_y (Y) = P(Y<y) = P(max(X1,X2)<y) = P(X1<y, X2<y) = P(X1<y)P(X2<y) = F_x(y)^2 $

$f(y) = (F_y(y))' = 2(F_x'(y)) = 2f_x(y) = 2 * {2y \over a^2}.$

So then the expected value of Y is $ \quad{4a \over 3 }$

And to find value of expected value and density of $Z$ I need to find cummulative distribution function for $Z$ and it is:

$F_z(z) = P(Z<z) = P(min(X1, X2)<z) = 1-P(min(X1,X2)>z) = 1-P(X1>z)P(X2>z) = 1 - [(1-P(X1<z))(1-P(X2<z))] = 1-(1-F_x(z))(1-F_x(z))] = 1-(1-F_x(z))^2 $

And then almost in the same way as for $Y$, I can find what I need.

Is it right? Should I find value of $a$ to solve the problem? If I should find value of $a$, how can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you found for expectation and variance of $X_1$ is correct.

There is a mistake in finding $f_Y(y)$.

You achieved correctly that $F_{Y}(y)=F_X(y)^2$ but differentiating leads to $f_Y(y)=2F_X(y)f_X(y)$.

Application of chain-rule.

It is not needed to go for finding values of **parameter** $a$.

Comment: okey, so the $ F_x(x) = \int_0^a {2x \over a^2} \, dx = 1 $, right? Then the value of expected value and density are correct, right?

Comment: As I said: the value for expected value and variance of $X_1$ are correct. What is meant by $F_x(x)$ in your comment? If $F$ denotes the CDF of $X_1$ then $F(x)=0$ if $x\leq0$, $F(x)=1$ if $x>a$ and $F(x)=\int_0^x\frac{2u}{a^2}du=[\frac{u^2}{a^2}]^x_0=\frac{x^2}{a^2}$ if $0<x\leq a$.

Comment: I meant the CDF of $X_1$ and $X_2$ because $F_{X_1} (x) = F_{X_2} (x)$, right?  Then $f_Y (y) = 0 $ if $ y ≤ 0$, $f_Y (y) = 2*1*f_X (y) = {4y \over a^2}$  if  $x > a$ and $f_Y (y) = 2*{4a \over 3} * {2x \over a^2} = {16a \over 3a} $ if $ 0 < x ≤ a$, right?

Comment: If $0<y<a$ then (see my answer and my former comment) $f_{Y}(y)=2F_{X}(y)f_{X}(y)=2\frac{y^{2}}{a^{2}}\frac{2y}{a^{2}}=\frac{4y^{3}}{a^{4}}$. For $y\leq0$ and $y\geq a$ the function takes value $0$.

Comment: Tell me one more thing. I know $F(x) = {\int_{p1}^{p2} f(x) \, dx} $. But why $p1 = 0$ and $p2 = x$ if we want $F(x)$ if $0 < x ≤ a$? Why did you use the integration limit ? Why not from $ 0 $ to $ a $ ?

Comment: Writing $F(x)=\int_p^q f(x)dx$ where $p$ and $q$ are constants is absurd. This because the LHS $F(x)$ is a *function varying in $x$* but the RHS $\int_p^q f(x)dx$ is *not a function*. As definite integral it is a real number. So the equality should imply that $F(x)$ is a constant function which is not the case. Actually $\int_p^q f(x)dx=F(q)-F(p)$.